# Rendering with Cycles with GPU, use tiles or not use tiles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu, tilesize

Is it faster to render using tiles or not?
Or does it depend on the scene? If so, what aspects of the scene would make it faster to use (or not use) tiles?

Also, if I'm rendering on the GPU and using tiles, should the tile size always be 256 (I've read somewhere that this size is faster for GPU rendering)?

For short: What can you tell me about using tiles when rendering in Cycles with GPU?

Answer (score 1):

Cycles before Blender 3.0: tiles. starting at 3.0: (cycles x) no tiles.

GPU: bigger is better but it depends on the gpu. there’s a addon that computes the best tile size included in Blender: auto tile size. from comments: only for pre 3.0 because cycles x should not use tiles.

Comment: That addon is automatically disabled when you update to 3.0. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/244994/no-auto-tile-size-in-blender-3-0