# How can I make CPU takeover render if GPU crashes?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

My GPU only has 12 GB of vRam, and I mainly use hybrid rendering, however if the GPU crashes, how can I make Cycles switch to the CPU so I don’t lose the render progress? I’ve been told to use an add on called ‘Auto Tile Size’, but when I go to activate it, it isn’t there.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/244994/no-auto-tile-size-in-blender-3-0

Comment: @JohnEason This post wasn’t really about Auto Tile Size, more about how to make the CPU take over if the GPU fails, but thanks for the info.